# Matlab - How to do this without dynamic variable / eval?

Tags: matlab, csv, dynamic, matrix, eval

My data collection software outputs the data as .csv files with the first row being the headings for each output, followed by rows containing the data (pretty standard I think). An example data file can found here: [Example data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1cv8czzbvtiqsm/GABA%20uncaging%20-%20distal-001_Cycle00001_VoltageRecording_001.csv)

This is the first point I am encountering an issue. Essentially when I import the file I get 2 matrices, one containing the headers (so just a [1xN] matrix, where N is the number of outputs. N changes between experiments, which is part of the problem here), and the other containing all the numeric data points. From this, I need to create arrays named using each of the headers in the "headers" matrix. I need to actually pull them out of the matrix, rather than just having a standard set of names that will the correspond to each of the columns in the "data" matrix because the number of outputs and potentially the names of the outputs is something that could (and often does) change between files.

I know that this can be done using the eval function, but I also know that the eval function should be avoided when possible. I am just at a loss of another way to go about doing this.

The next level of complexity, which I think the solution (if there is one) will be similar to the solution above, is that I need to maintain the folder structure in the form of nested structures. This is because I will need to be able to import a number of these files all at once.

So, just to give an example, the nested structure would look something like this:

[File Structure](http://i319.photobucket.com/albums/mm462/DGalt11/FileStructure_Small_zpsf4894f31.png)

A typical file path will look something like: 
H:\RawData\11-01-13\Cell1\ProximalDendrite_001\Sweep1.csv

etc., where Sweep1 would correspond to a VoltageOutputs file like the one I linked (there are generally multiple sweeps per folder).

The idea then is to have a matrix for each sweep that contains the various OutputVariable arrays. There are multiple sweeps per data folder, and each of those data folders is contained in a larger folder for that data set. I need to be able to name the matrices that will contain all of this based on the file names to which they correspond.

The idea is to ultimately have something where I can call on a specific array from a specific sweep. So, using the example above, I could call on the "Primary" output from Outputs001 from Dendrite001 from Cell1 using:

11-01-13_Cell1.ProximalDenrite_001.Sweep1.Primary

So, again, there is the need to be able to name those things by first looking at how they are named already (which is easy enough to get), saving that string, and somehow renaming the matrix with that corresponding name.

Which again, is possible using the eval function, but if an alternative exists I'd certainly like to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar where I create a struct where each field name comes from the header information in the file. Mine is quite elaborate and I don't have access to that code right now but its basically something like this:

```
% use the header field as the name and assign all rows to that vector
for nidx = 1:length(headers)
   structname.(headers{nidx}) = data(:,nidx);
end
```

As long as your header field names are valid Matlab variable names its rather simple, otherwise you need to translate characters to remove any invalid ones first from each header string.

Comment: I see how you can make every level after the first level doing this. However, can you think of a way to name the structure itself using the name of the file itself. So, for example, the name of the structure I have in my example is 11-01-13_Cell1

I mean, potentially I would just have to make default structures (e.g.DataSet1), which would work as a workaround, but obviously isn't ideal.